# Parsear un map a JSON

Tags: webservice, angular5

Estoy consumiendo una API desde angular , mi problema va cuando quiero es llenar de datos un chip autocomplete para eso estoy usando angular2-materialize,pero segun su estructura se debe ver de esta manera:

```
autocompleteInit = {
  autocompleteOptions: {
    data: {
      'Apple': null,
      'Microsoft': null,
      'Google': null
    },
    limit: Infinity,
    minLength: 1
  }
};
```

Este seria mi codigo de angular:
Servicio:

```
 getAlltags():Observable<Array<Tag>> {
    return this.http.post<Array<Tag>>(this.url + "list", "");

  }
```

Componente que quiero utilizar los datos:

```
this.tagService.getAlltags().subscribe((tagsParametro) => {
      console.log(tagsParametro)
      this.tags = tagsParametro;
      tagsParametro.forEach(tag => {
        this.map.set(tag.name, null);
      })
      console.log(JSON.stringify([this.map]))
      this.autocompleteInit.autocompleteOptions.data = tagsParametro;
      console.log(this.autocompleteInit.autocompleteOptions)
    }
```

Como se puede observar traigo un Array de "tags" que tiene atributos name:string,id:number,color:string
pero solo quiero el nombre por eso creo un map donde solo agrego los nombres,
pero quiero que se convierta en JSON para poder utilizarlo en angular, al igual que el modelo especificamente "data"

Answer (score 0):

```
let array = [ 
  { id: 1,  name: 'Apple', color: 'red' },
  { id: 2,  name: 'Microsoft', color: 'white' },
  { id: 3,  name: 'Google', color: 'blue' } ];

let names = array.map(m => m.name);

let obj: {[k: string]: null} = {};

names.forEach(function (value) {
    obj[value] = null;
}); 

console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

Con esto se imprime

```
{"Apple":null,"Microsoft":null,"Google":null}
```